# xcode compile options

Tags: xcode, compilation

I am compiling from the command line with

```
gcc -o output-file $(mysql_config --cflags) main.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

How can I add the extra params to xcode compiling options?

gcc -o output-file **$(mysql_config --cflags)** main.c **$(mysql_config --libs)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple-I the project file, there is a section in build settings

Other C Flags
Other linker flags

If you are using Xcode >= 4 you need to click on the Project in the Navigator then click on the Target. Finally, click on the "Build Settings" tab. Type in the search field "other c" and you should see you fields there. If put  "$(mysql_config --cflags) $(mysql_config --libs)" in one of the fields depending on what language you are using (c or c++).
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate.. I'm having trouble figuring it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode -- found offsetof(struct structureName, memberName) as a standard c function